# GRUB menu will not load in dual boot Linux & Windows 10 on UEFI/GPT

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

After updating my Dell G3 3579 bios to 1.12.0, Ubuntu stopped loading. When I checked, issue is related with BIOS/UEFI mode and MBR/GPT partitions.

So, I installed both Window 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 from start with UEFI mode, GPT partitions.
However, Ubuntu does not load either.

Both bootable USB are made by Rufus with GPT option.
There are SSD and HDD inside laptop, but both OS are installed in SSD only.
Secure Boot is disabled. Fastboot is turned off.

Boot Repair runs successful and Ubuntu is at the top of UEFI setting but GRUB menu does not load. Please check Pastebin link here ---> http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2n4ds6qT3V/

Run bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi from window cmd. not loading too.

Please suggest me a way to solve this issue. Thanks.

P.S. even tried installing Manjaro, GRUB menu not showing ...

Comment: I found that `refind` is a good bootloader to get things working with sane/smart default values, before replacing it with grub. We're discussing `grub-efi` correct?

Comment: @Pedro. yes, `grub-efi` . will check that bootloader, thanks.

Comment: There is no fixed recipe to fix these issues, it's wholly dependent on what you have done and what you want the outcome to be. The tools of the trade are the bootloaders, partitioning tools, live linux discs, etc. If you want a good answer, you need to post something a whole lot more specific than that.

Comment: @Pedro, which information is still required? I wrote as far as I did. 
What I want is ubuntu and window 10 dual boot in UEFI mood. Normally grub boot repair should fix the issue and Ubuntu will boot. but not ok in my case.

Comment: why would grub boot repair fix the issue, if you don't know what the issue is? with UEFI there's no such thing as boot partitions. the bootloader reads the EFI partition which is often fat/vfat formatted (seems to be your sdb1 and it contains boot loaders for windows and linux). nothing on your pastebin stands out. try to get refind installed and configured to boot both OSs, take note of the details and then try to replace it with grub-efi.

Comment: also, with UEFI, the actual boot program can act like a boot manager and allow you to choose with OS to boot (much like grub does) at the time of choosing your boot media.

Comment: thanks for explanation. at least I get what to try next.